# from subreport to main report

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I have a crystal report that shows the data in this way:

code_*price*___qty

A_**_*10.00*___**_1

B_**_*20.00*___**_1

A_**_*10.00*___**_1

and in the footer I have a subreport that group by code and sum the price, so:

A_*_*_20.00

B_*_*_20.00

Now, I would like to have in the MAIN report the total of A + B, ie 40.00

how do I?

I can not take a value from the subreport to the main report..thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you even using a subreport? You could accomplish this by grouping on the code in the main report.

Comment: Understood. It is sometimes difficult to balance 1) presenting a simplified version of your issue with 2) ensuring your simplified version is a close-enough approximation of your actual problem. Best of luck to you.

Comment: To do it quickly, I've been too simplistic, actually reality is this:
I have a report that shows the following data: PROD___PRICE___VAT.

and a subreport that groups based on VAT: VAT____AMOUNT___TAXVAT.

I would, in the main report, summary to make the Grand Total:

TotAmount___TotTaxVat

say I can use the method described by you?

thank you very much
bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

- Copy the summary field that is located in the group footer
- Paste the summary field in the report-footer section
- Remove the subreport; you can do all of this without one
- Create a Running Total to calculate the value of A:

[image]

- Change "Field to summarize" to table.Price
- The formula should be similar to `{table.Code}="A"`
- Place field in report-footer section
- Create second RT field for B